# Save change String on restart in Android

Tags: android, string, save, restart

Im building an app where I have an Array list with strings and a button.
When I press the button it deletes the string from the list (with string.remove) and display it in another activity..
The problem is that when I close the app and reopen it everything goes back to normal. How to save the changes made?

Here is the code:

```
     public class TasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static ArrayList<String> list;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

    final Button tasksbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfortasks);
    Button checkTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_case);

    final TextView tasksView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tasks_textView);



    final ArrayList<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
    tasks.add("one");
    tasks.add("two");
    tasks.add("three");
    tasks.add("four");
    tasks.add("five");
    tasks.add("six");





    Collections.shuffle(tasks);
    tasksView.setText(tasks.get(0));


    assert tasksbtn != null;
    tasksbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Collections.shuffle(tasks);
            tasksView.setText(tasks.get(0));


        }
    });



    checkTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TasksActivity.this, CompletedTasks.class);
            intent.putExtra("completedTasks", tasks.get(0));
            tasks.remove(tasks.get(0));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }); 


}



 }
```

And the second Activity

```
    public class CompletedTasks extends AppCompatActivity {

String completedTasks;
Global_Variable object = new Global_Variable();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_completed_tasks);


    TextView completedTasksView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completed_tasks);


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    completedTasks = intent.getExtras().getString("completedTasks");
    object.tasks.add(completedTasks + "\n");



    String a = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < object.tasks.size(); i++) {
        a += object.tasks.get (i);
        completedTasksView.setText(a);
        Log.d("a", "a---------" + a);


    }

}
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the negative vote.. Its really helpfull.. :/

Comment: It's probably because you didn't provide any code. Often it's hard to help or understand what you try to achieve without seeing the code.

Comment: Ok I will provide my code but I think its more helpfull to learn this in a general way like shared preferences @babadaba mentioned.. (Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably give try to serialization. Please take look over below sample example.

```
 public class SerializationDemo extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("CoderzHeaven");
    person.setAddress("CoderzHeaven India");
    person.setNumber("1234567890"); 

    //save the object
    saveObject(person);

    // Get the Object
    Person person1 = (Person)loadSerializedObject(new File("/sdcard/save_object.bin")); //get the serialized object from the sdcard and caste it into the Person class.
    System.out.println("Name : " + person1.getName());
}

public void saveObject(Person p){
     try
     {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/save_object.bin"))); //Select where you wish to save the file...
        oos.writeObject(p); // write the class as an 'object'
        oos.flush(); // flush the stream to insure all of the information was written to 'save_object.bin'
        oos.close();// close the stream
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        Log.v("Serialization Save Error : ",ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
}

public Object loadSerializedObject(File f)
{
    try
    {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        return o;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    Log.v("Serialization Read Error : ",ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
 Person implements Serializable //Added implements Serializable
{
String name="";
private String number="";
private String address=""; 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 46543445; 

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public void setNumber(String number)
{
    this.number = number;
}

public void setAddress(String address)
{
    this.address = address;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getNumber()
{
    return number;
}

public String getAddress()
{
    return address;
}
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving your changes to the SharedPreferences. Then when you resatrt your app, read the changes from your ShraredPreferences and apply it to your ListView or whatever you are using.

You can read more about SharedPreferences here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: So the SharedPreferences saves the list if I delete a string so it wont be seen again?

Comment: Yes. You should probably work with a ListView or a RecyclerView to display your tasks. Using a TextView with \n is not a common practice.

Comment: Ok I will try your way.. Thanks :)